# ${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS} not working for s3 camel from uri

Tags: amazon-s3, apache-camel, spring-camel

I have tried few days to achieve with replacement of date/time as specified format with from(s3bucketuri).  But, it's not working. Its simply replacing the string constant directly when doing moveAfterRead=true.

I am using this below uri:

`aws2-s3://testbucket-hel?accessKey=RAW(xxx)&secretKey=RAW(xxx)&moveAfterRead=true&destinationBucket=myBucket&destinationBucketPrefix=+"${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS}`

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you using `.toD` instead of `.to`? ([Apache Camel dynamic URI](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/faq/how-to-use-a-dynamic-uri-in-to.html))

Comment: No, I am using &moveAfterRead=true&destinationBucket=myBucket options in query string so that the file will be move automatically after reading.

Comment: [simple](https://camel.apache.org/components/3.12.x/languages/simple-language.html) expressions like `${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS}` only work in URI's if you're using `.toD`  where as `.to` will treat them like a regular string.

Comment: You could try something like `.toD("aws2-s3://testbucket-hel?accessKey=RAW(xxx)&secretKey=RAW(xxx)&moveAfterRead=true&destinationBucket=myBucket&destinationBucketPrefix=${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS}")` albeit I am not sure if `${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS}` returns valid string for `destinationBucketPrefix`.

Comment: With destinationBucketPrefix this expression is not working. Will double check once.

Comment: I've not used `aws2-s3` component myself so can't really help you with that but I do know that one needs to use .toD to use simple expressions in producer endpoint URI and that `=+`  you have in   `&destinationBucketPrefix=+"${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmssSS}` is probably not valid syntax for query parameter but I am guessing that's just a typo and you're missing couple quotation marks from your uri.